# Regex returning part of match instead false when it passes the length

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a number sequence starts with 4 and have exactly 12 to 15 more digits (the number length has to have from 13 to 16 digits).

I expect my regex works returning false when it's less or greater than {12,15}.

I'm testing this regex: `4{1}\d{12,15}` that works when numbers is less than  13 digits, in this case it returns false, but when it passes from 15 digits it returns just de part of string instead be null. 
Ex:

With: `412345678901` preg_match() returns:

```
array()
```

With: `412345678901234567` preg_match() returns:

```
array(
    0 => 4123456789012345
)
```

In second case I wanted it to be false too, because the length is greater than 15 that I setted on Regex.

Comment: `preg_match` is from php isn't it?

Comment: Try using anchors `^4\d{12,15}$`

Comment: Yes, it's I'm just testing on PHP Live Regex. But will use this on JS "string".match()

Comment: @Thefourthbird I tried with ^4\d{12,15}$, but when I add $ it not works. I found it strange.

Comment: Can you share the code that you tried?

Comment: I not implemented on code yet, I'm just trying on PHPLiveRegex yet to build my regex

Comment: Did you test it like this? [`^4\d{12,15}$`](https://regex101.com/r/zaZKRQ/1) or like https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/org

Comment: @Thefourthbird 's solution works for me

Comment: @Thefourthbird Work it worked perfectly! I discovered I was using '&' instead of '$'  OMG kkkkkk Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use anchors `^` and `$` to assert the start and the end of the string.

You can omit the `{1}` quantifier.

[`^4\d{12,15}$`](https://regex101.com/r/D7tzDY/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "4666666666666",
  "466666666666",
  "46666666666666777"

];
let pattern = /^4\d{12,15}$/;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/XKPrb)